# Convert date string PHP

Tags: php, string, date, variables, strtotime

I had the string beneath out of `$datum = $_COOKIE['ingevoerde_datum'];`:

`[[52,2,"2020-01-10 15:00:00",0]]`

I stripped it to:
`2020/01/10`

I did that by doing this:

```
$datum_zonder_eind = substr_replace($datum, '', -14) . "<br />\n";
$datum_zonder_begin = substr($datum_zonder_eind, strpos($datum_zonder_eind, "_") + 8);    
$streepje = str_replace('-', '/', $datum_zonder_begin);
echo $streepje;
```

Now I want to convert it to a date,
found this online:

```
$input = $streepje; 
$date = strtotime($input); 
echo date('D/M/Y H:i:s', $date);
```

But this gives me:
`Thu/Jan/1970 01:00:00`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try deleting this line: `$streepje = str_replace('-', '/', $datum_zonder_begin);` - **2020-01-10** is a valid date string (for `strtotime()` anyway) ... I'm not sure that **2010/01/10** is.

Comment: Does not have any effect

Comment: The random `<br />` you'd appended to the date string wasn't doing it any favours either...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply do `explode()`, remove the quotas and then use the original date from the string:

```
<?php
    $str = '[[52,2,"2020-01-10 15:00:00",0]]';
    $strArray = explode(',', $str);
    $strDate = str_replace('"', '', $strArray[2]);
    echo $date = date('D/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($strDate));
?>
```

Output:

```
Fri/Jan/2020 15:00:00
```

Of course, you can play with `date()` formats if you need a bit different output.